# How to check if an array is empty or exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When the page is loading for the first time, I need to check if there is an image in `image_array` and load the last image.

Otherwise, I disable the preview buttons, alert the user to push new image button and create an empty array to put the images;

The problem is that `image_array` in the `else` fires all time. If an array exists - it just overrides it, but alert doesn't work.

```
if(image_array.length > 0)
    $('#images').append('<img src="'+image_array[image_array.length-1]+'" class="images" id="1" />');
else{
    $('#prev_image').attr('disabled', 'true');
    $('#next_image').attr('disabled', 'true');
    alert('Please get new image');
    var image_array = [];
}
```

UPDATE
Before loading html, I have something like this:

```
<?php if(count($images) != 0): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo "image_array = ".json_encode($images);?>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Console log `image_array` - what do you get?

Comment: @Utkanos if there is var image_array = [] -  undefined 

if //var image_array = [] (comented) - real array.

Comment: array?.length - widely supported and will be a native feature soon

Answer (score 694, accepted):

```
if (typeof image_array !== 'undefined' && image_array.length > 0) {
    // the array is defined and has at least one element
}
```

Your problem may be happening due to a mix of implicit global variables and variable hoisting. Make sure you use `var` whenever declaring a variable:

```
<?php echo "var image_array = ".json_encode($images);?>
// add var  ^^^ here
```

And then make sure you never accidently redeclare that variable later:

```
else {
    ...
    image_array = []; // no var here
}
```

Comment: Nope. This will blast when image_array is null. Murphy's law states that some day it will.

Comment: Isn't `image_array.length` enough? (without specifying `>0`)

Comment: Curious: Can you find any use case that would break using the answer of @JamesDrinkard?

Comment: `if (image_array && image_array.length){ // array exists and has elements`

Comment: This fails for `let image_array = new Array(10);`.

Comment: ```Array.isArray(arr);``` enjoy

Comment: i faced situation that var test_array = new Array();, then started function and inside the function with typeof test_array get object, but if (typeof test_array !== 'undefined') { get false and with if (typeof test_array != 'undefined') { get true. So array exists, but with !== i get that as if does not exist. Finally problem was becaus of my negligance. I had html id with the same name as array name. That is why typeof !== did not work as expected.

Answer (score 346):

## To check if an array is either empty or not

A modern way, ES5+:

```js
if (Array.isArray(array) && array.length) {
    // array exists and is not empty
}
```

An old-school way:

```js
typeof array != "undefined"
    && array != null
    && array.length != null
    && array.length > 0
```

A compact way:

```js
if (typeof array != "undefined" && array != null && array.length != null && array.length > 0) {
    // array exists and is not empty
}
```

A CoffeeScript way:

```js
if array?.length > 0
```

---

### Why?

**Case Undefined**
Undefined variable is a variable that you haven't assigned anything to it yet.

```js
let array = new Array();     // "array" !== "array"
typeof array == "undefined"; // => true
```

**Case Null**
Generally speaking, null is state of lacking a value. For example a variable is null when you missed or failed to retrieve some data.

```js
array = searchData();  // can't find anything
array == null;         // => true
```

**Case Not an Array**
Javascript has a dynamic type system. This means we can't guarantee what type of object a variable holds. There is a chance that we're not talking to an instance of `Array`.

```js
supposedToBeArray =  new SomeObject();
typeof supposedToBeArray.length;       // => "undefined"

array = new Array();
typeof array.length;                   // => "number"
```

**Case Empty Array**
Now since we tested all other possibilities, we're talking to an instance of `Array`. In order to make sure it's not empty, we ask about number of elements it's holding, and making sure it has more than zero elements.

```js
firstArray = [];
firstArray.length > 0;  // => false

secondArray = [1,2,3];
secondArray.length > 0; // => true
```

Comment: Please note that it is **not** sufficient to just check for `(typeof array != "undefined" && array.length > 0)` because if `array` is null we'll get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

Comment: Maybe change && with ||

Comment: `!(typeof array !== "undefined") || !(array.length > 0)`? Just tried it, got same error. Can you give us a full example of how to use `||`?

Comment: I meant `(typeof array != "undefined" || array.length > 0)`

Comment: Thanks for clarification. `(typeof array != "undefined" || array.length > 0)` returns `true` if `array = null`. `!(typeof array != "undefined" || array.length > 0)` returns `false` if `array = [1,2]`. Sorry for not understanding, but @Elsa can you provide a working example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `array.length != null` is needed to be sure that what we have is an array, why can we then omit it when doing the compact way?

Comment: @Aenadon Both `undefined > 0` and `null > 0` evaluate to `false`; evaluation of an undefined property on a defined object returns `undefined`. This is a trick; we really shouldn't use tricks. I'm going to remove it.

Comment: Re `.. && array.length)`. IMHO, while you *can* safely rely on JS's loose-typing, to convert a `0` integer to `false` and a `non-zero` integer to `true`, I consider it preferable, for readability in the future, to "say what you mean". I would do `.. && array.length > 0)`.

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 78):

How about (ECMA 5.1):

```
if(Array.isArray(image_array) && image_array.length){
  // array exists and is not empty
}
```

Comment: Re `.. && image_array.length)`. IMHO, while you *can* safely rely on JS's loose-typing, to convert a `0` integer to `false` and a `non-zero` integer to `true`, I consider it preferable, for readability in the future, to "say what you mean". I would do `.. && image_array.length > 0)`.

Answer (score 70):

This is what I use.  The first condition covers truthy, which has both null and undefined.  Second condition checks for an empty array.

```
if(arrayName && arrayName.length > 0){
    //do something.
}
```

or thanks to tsemer's comment I added a second version

```
if(arrayName && arrayName.length)
```

Then I made a test for the second condition, using Scratchpad in Firefox:

```js
var array1;
var array2 = [];
var array3 = ["one", "two", "three"];
var array4 = null;

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);
console.log(array4);

if (array1 && array1.length) {
  console.log("array1! has a value!");
}

if (array2 && array2.length) {
  console.log("array2! has a value!");
}

if (array3 && array3.length) {
  console.log("array3! has a value!");
}

if (array4 && array4.length) {
  console.log("array4! has a value!");
}
```

***which also proves that `if(array2 && array2.length)` and `if(array2 && array2.length > 0)` are exactly doing the same***

Comment: Short and quick! It took me a while coming from C# to get used to if(obj) to check for null, but now I love it: if(obj) // null check; if(array && array.length) // array null or empty check; if(array && !array.length) // array exists, but empty check; if(str) // string not null and not empty. The only gotcha is don't use on numbers if zero is a valid number.

Comment: In Typescript there are nuances, as for `var arrayName = undefined; var isNotEmpty = arrayName && array.length > 0` type for isNotEmpty would not be boolean, it would be boolean|undefined.

Answer (score 63):

## [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

As optional chaining proposal reached stage 4 and is getting wider support, there is a very elegant way to do this

```js
if(image_array?.length){

  // image_array is defined and has at least one element

}
```

Answer (score 19):

You should use:

```
  if (image_array !== undefined && image_array.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to test whether the image array variable had been defined you can do it like this

```
if(typeof image_array === 'undefined') {
    // it is not defined yet
} else if (image_array.length > 0) {
    // you have a greater than zero length array
}
```

Comment: Not working https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202012-07-31%20%D0%B2%2018.25.27.png

Comment: @user1564141 hard to tell where the function is being declared relative to your image_array being set. You might be having a hosting issue, so you might need to declare that variable as var index_array = ...  Also, is the script tag where you set index_array being closed.  It does not appear so from the screenshot.

Comment: In the else also is alert, wich fires only when array is empty, but the var image_array works every time... I cant understand why?

Comment: @user1564141 It would help if you could update your question to show the source as output.  I still don't have a feel for where your if-else logic resides within the source relative to the location of your index_array declaration.

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript

```
( typeof(myArray) !== 'undefined' && Array.isArray(myArray) && myArray.length > 0 )
```

Lodash & Underscore

```
( _.isArray(myArray) && myArray.length > 0 )
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery's `isEmptyObject()` to check whether the array contains elements or not.

```
var testArray=[1,2,3,4,5]; 
var testArray1=[];
console.log(jQuery.isEmptyObject(testArray)); //false
console.log(jQuery.isEmptyObject(testArray1)); //true
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me when adding elements with array.push() - from dynamically added elements (ajax). Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using [undescore](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isArray):

`_.isArray(image_array) && !_.isEmpty(image_array)`

Answer (score 3):

A simple way that doesn't result in exceptions if not exist and convert to boolean:

```
!!array
```

Example:

```
if (!!arr) {
  // array exists
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this ? checking for length of undefined array may throw exception.

```
if(image_array){
//array exists
    if(image_array.length){
    //array has length greater than zero
    }
}
```

Comment: The nested `if` can be avoided using `&&`, as in `image_array && image_array.length`, it will short circuit if `image_array` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

The best is to check like:

```
    let someArray: string[] = [];
    let hasAny1: boolean = !!someArray && !!someArray.length;
    let hasAny2: boolean = !!someArray && someArray.length > 0; //or like this
    console.log("And now on empty......", hasAny1, hasAny2);
```

See full samples list:
[image: code sample]
[image: results]

Answer (score 2):

I come across this issue quite a lot in Javascript. For me the best way to do it is to put a very broad check before checking for length. I saw some other solutions in this Q&A, but I wanted to be able to check for either `null` or `undefined` or any other false value.

```
if(!array || array.length == 0){
    console.log("Array is either empty or does not exist")
}
```

This will first check for `undefined`, `null`, or other false values. If any of those are true, it will complete the boolean as this is an `OR`. Then the more risky check of `array.length`, which could error us if array is undefined, can be checked. This will never be reached if `array` is `undefined` or `null`, so the ordering of conditions is very important.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a variable declared as array you can create a check:

```
if(x && x.constructor==Array && x.length){
   console.log("is array and filed");
}else{
    var x= [];
    console.log('x = empty array');
}
```

This checks if variable x exists and if it is, checks if it is a filled array. else it creates an empty array (or you can do other stuff);

If you are **certain** there is an array variable created there is a simple check:

```
var x = [];

if(!x.length){
    console.log('empty');
} else {
    console.log('full');
}
```

You can check [my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dqtngu6h/1/) with shows most possible ways to check array.

Answer (score 1):

> The following is my solution wrapped in a function that also throws
>   errors to manage a couple of problems with object scope and all types
>   of possible data types passed to the function.

Here's my fiddle used to examine this problem ([source](https://jsfiddle.net/mingsai/8oub4L75/))

```
var jill = [0];
var jack;
//"Uncaught ReferenceError: jack is not defined"

//if (typeof jack === 'undefined' || jack === null) {
//if (jack) {
//if (jack in window) {
//if (window.hasOwnP=roperty('jack')){
//if (jack in window){

function isemptyArray (arraynamed){
    //cam also check argument length
  if (arguments.length === 0) { 
    throw "No argument supplied";
  }

  //console.log(arguments.length, "number of arguments found");
  if (typeof arraynamed !== "undefined" && arraynamed !== null) {
      //console.log("found arraynamed has a value");
      if ((arraynamed instanceof Array) === true){
        //console.log("I'm an array");
        if (arraynamed.length === 0) {
            //console.log ("I'm empty");
            return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }//end length check
      } else {
        //bad type
        throw "Argument is not an array";
      } //end type check
  } else {
    //bad argument
    throw "Argument is invalid, check initialization";;
  }//end argument check
}

try {
  console.log(isemptyArray(jill));
} catch (e) {
    console.log ("error caught:",e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the way I found to work (comming from another language) is to make a simple function to test.

create a function that check the size of the array and pass the lenght by parameter.

```
isEmpty(size){
        if(size==0) {
            return true;
        } else  {
            return false;
        }
    }

//then check
if(isEmpty(yourArray.length)==true){
            //its empty
        } else {
            //not empty
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me sure some of the high rated answers "work" when I put them into jsfiddle, but when I have a dynamically generated amount of array list a lot of this code in the answers just doesn't work for ME.

**This is what IS working for me.**

```
var from = [];

if(typeof from[0] !== undefined) {
  //...
}
```

Notice,  NO quotes around undefined and I'm not bothering with the length.

Comment: two comments:
1) `typeof` returns a string, comparing to `undefined` will always be flasy
2) you don't check if `from` is defined. your code above will throw an error if it's not

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
    if (!image_array) {
      // image_array defined but not assigned automatically coerces to false
    } else if (!(0 in image_array)) {
      // empty array
      // doSomething
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `image_array` is not array but some OBJECT with `length` property (like string) - try

```
if(image_array instanceof Array && image_array.length)
```

```js
function test(image_array) {
  if(image_array instanceof Array && image_array.length) { 
    console.log(image_array,'- it is not empty array!')
  } else {
    console.log(image_array,'- it is empty array or not array at all!')
  }
}

test({length:5});
test('undefined');
test([]);
test(["abc"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `array_.length` always returned 0, even if it had values inside. Probably, because of non-default indexes.

So to check if array is defined we use `typeof _array !== 'undefined'`
And then to check if it contains any date i just simply compare it to an empty array `_array !== []`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if (Array.isArray(arr) && !arr.length) {
  console.log("Array is an array and is empty");
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. It's interested in the condition where the array is non-empty, which is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940191/) already.

Comment: Please elaborate on how your code works and how it fixes OP's problem

Answer (score -1):

in ts

```
 isArray(obj: any) 
{
    return Array.isArray(obj)
  }
```

in html

(photos == undefined || !(isArray(photos) && photos.length > 0) )

Comment: Are you sure about that? The second part does not look like HTML after all

Answer (score -4):

When you create your image_array, it's empty, therefore your image_array.length is 0

As stated in the comment below, i edit my answer based on this  [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)) :

```
var image_array = []
```

inside the else brackets doesn't change anything to the image_array defined before in the code

Comment: I have it in the source, when loading page... Just forget to post.

Comment: I want to add something to my answer that may be wrong so i state it here. In common languages, what is created inside a block is not visible "outside" the block. As you define `[]var image_array = []` inside the else block, i'm not sure it could be seen outside. Try `image_array = []`

Comment: but if i remove image_array from the else everything works just fine.