# checking an object for null element

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, arrayobject

The response from a http GET method is as shown below:

```
{
  id:1,
  name:"John",
  subjects:[],
  totalMarks:458
}
```

In the front end I want to check whether the `subjects` property is empty or not.
I have tried with this approach but not working

```
var newObj= {
    id:1,
    name:"John",
    subjects:[],
    totalMarks:458
}

if (newObj.subjects == null) {
  alert("Empty subjects");
}
```

Comment: will `subjects` be always an Array? Will always be defined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if array is empty or exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists)

Comment: The answer to your problem is there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons/359509#359509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newObj.subjects` is `Array`, so you need check it like this

```
if(Array.isArray(newObj.subjects) && !newObj.subjects.length) {
   alert("Empty subjects");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `length` property to check if the array is empty..

```
 if(newObj.subjects.length==0)
    {
       alert("Empty subjects");
    }
```