# How to check if there is at least one element in a multidimensional array? (Silly Basic Javascript Questionn)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to check if there is at least one element in an array? (I want to verify if the array is not empty.)

Sorry for this silly question, I already spent too much time on Google... (Google only returns complex situations and solutions. It seems like my question is too simple.).

EDIT:  Ok, but what will happen with an array like [,,[],,[],,,] ?  For my purposes, it should be considered as empty.

EDIT 2: Sorry, guys, for the confusion! At first, I didn't even know exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all!

Comment: Use the array length property. If it is greater than 0 it has an element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if array is empty or exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists)

Comment: `array.length > 0 && array[0].length > 0` (repeat for as many dimensions as you have)

Comment: How come you have the `multidimensional-array` tag? Can you give an example of the structure of your array?

Comment: @user2005218  Thanks

Comment: @qxz I might get something like that: arr = [,,[],,[],,,]    For my purposes [,,[],,[],,,] is empty, while [,,["a"],,[],,,] is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would fulfill your new requirements:

```
function isEmpty(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
        return false;
    }

    return arr.every(isEmpty);
}
```

What it does: with the help of `Array.prototype.every` it checks that the every item left is an empty array. And the array holes are automatically skipped by `.every()`.

References:

- [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: This would only work for a second dimension, right? Any clue on how to reach the third, fourth or fifth dimension?

Comment: @Emilio it is recursive and would work with any depth. `isEmpty([,,,[[],[],,,,[[[]]]],,,]) // true`

Answer (score -1):

You could also use truthiness here. This would help you check against undefined at the same time. [] is falsy, so you could do this:

```
var arr = [];

if(!arr) {
  ... arr is undefined or empty array
} else {
  ... arr has at least one value
}
```

Comment: Wrong, `[]` is truthy. Try it in your browser console.

Comment: That's just not true.. `[]` is true, `[1]` is too

Comment: Odd: [] == true is false

Comment: @user3191461 in JS being "truthy" does not mean "equal to `true`"