# How to verify that a list is empty in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is clear  i guess, i have the bellow code in my controller

```
vf.filtroses = [];
    FiltrosService.currentuser().success(function(data, status) {
        vf.filtroses = data;
    });
```

i want to verify if vf.filtroses has elements or it's empty.
i tryed .lenght and equals:

```
vf.nofiltros = false;
    vf.filtroses = [];
    FiltrosService.currentuser().success(function(data, status) {
        vf.filtroses = data;
    });
    if(angular.equals([], vf.filtroses)){
        vf.nofiltros = true;
    }
```

but it does not work for me !

any ideas plz??

Comment: And if (vf.filtroses.length < 1) { } won't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if array is empty or exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists)

Comment: i tried all this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the size check inside the success function:

```
FiltrosService.currentuser().success(function(data, status) {
    vf.filtroses = data;
    if(!(vf.filtroses && vf.filtroses.length>0)){
             vf.nofiltros = true;
             }
    });
```

Comment: yeah that's what i was messing

Comment: You can simplify this code to: `vf.nofiltros = !vf.filtroses || !vf.filtroses.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.length**  to check the length of the array or list of objects.

```
vf.nofiltros = false;
vf.filtroses = [];
FiltrosService.currentuser().success(function(data, status) {
    vf.filtroses = data;

    vf.nofiltros = vf.filtroses && vf.filtroses.length > 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check null or undefined will solve your problem.

```
if(vf.filtroses!==undefined && vf.filtroses!=null){
    vf.nofiltros = true;
}
```