# Javascript: How to check my variable is empty or not using JavaScript Type Conversion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I tried to `initialize` an empty array in `JavaScript` but it return something in it. then I tried with `typescript` it allow to `initialize` empty array. but I want it in JavaScript so how can I do?

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

javascript code:

```
var emptyArr = [];
var emptyString = "";
var emptyNumber;
var numberWithZeroValue = 0;
var emptyBoolean = false;
console.log("emptyArr: " + !!emptyArr);
console.log("emptyString: " + !!emptyString);
console.log("emptyNumber: " + !!emptyNumber);
console.log("numberWithZeroValue: " + !!numberWithZeroValue);
console.log("emptyBoolean: " + !!emptyBoolean);
```

output:

```
emptyArr: true        //it returning somthing in it.
emptyString: false
emptyNumber: false
numberWithZeroValue: false
emptyBoolean: false
```

**`javascript` does't allow to declare type of variable so I tried with `typescript`.**

typescript code:

```
var emptyArr: Array;
var emptyString: String = "";
var emptyNumber: Number;
var numberWithZeroValue: Number = 0;
var emptyBoolean: Boolean = false;

console.log("emptyArr: " + !!emptyArr);
console.log("emptyString: " + !!emptyString);
console.log("emptyNumber: " + !!emptyNumber);
console.log("numberWithZeroValue: " + !!numberWithZeroValue);
console.log("emptyBoolean: " + !!emptyBoolean);
```

output:

```
emptyArr: false     //it returning empty array.
emptyString: false
emptyNumber: false
numberWithZeroValue: false
emptyBoolean: false
```

**Note:** `typescript` return an array is empty but `javascript` return something in it.

Update:
I don't want to check with array.length because my variable is any of type like `String`, `Number`, `Array`, `Boolean`, etc. I want to check it like `return !!myVariable`

Comment: let emptyArr: Array = [] ?

Comment: You need to learn the syntax of both languages. Start with JavaScript.

Comment: it's a problem of definition. What is considered an empty array and _how to check if it's empty_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if array is empty or exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists)

Answer (score 4):

**You did create an empty** `Array`, no problems with your creation code.

An `Array` in Javascript is considered *empty* **if it holds no elements**.

You check for an empty array in Javascript like this:

```
console.log("emptyArr: " + !!emptyArr.length);
```

```js
let emptyArr = []; // or new Array();
console.log("emptyArr: " + !!emptyArr.length);
if (emptyArr.length) {
  console.log("Array is not empty");
} else {
  console.log("Array is empty");
}
```

Since the following values evaluate to `false` in a Boolean expression in Javascript

> `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, `false`

instead of `if (!!emptyArr.length)` you simply go `if (emptyArr.length)` in Javascript. These values (except `false`) are called **falsy** in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This the proper way to check for an empty array in javascript

```js
var emptyArr = [];
var emptyString = "";
var emptyNumber;
var numberWithZeroValue = 0;
var emptyBoolean = false;
if(emptyArr.length == 0){
console.log(" its an emptyArr");
}

console.log("emptyString: " + !!emptyString);
console.log("emptyNumber: " + !!emptyNumber);
console.log("numberWithZeroValue: " + !!numberWithZeroValue);
console.log("emptyBoolean: " + !!emptyBoolean);
```

Comment: In real life, you'd do `if(emptyArr.length)`.

Comment: @connexo i know  , i didnt want to do it because it seems that the OP is not familiar with javascript yet

Answer (score 0):

you can declare array in typescript like this.

```
var alphas:any[];
```

Comment: I want it in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to know why vanillaJS array initialization equals `true` and typescript `false`.

This is because of the typescript transpiler. It transpiles `var emptyArr: Array;` into `var emptyArr;` and now you've the same result as your third vanillaJS line (`var emptyNumber;`).