# Replace an empty array inside the array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I am using the map (several map getting the necessary elements inside the nested json) function. I am trying to get an output from the Neo4j database according to desired template. During the last map I am building part of desired output having this stored inside variable:

```
 px.segments.map(function(pathSegment){                                                                                          
  individual_path.push({                          
   "start": pathSegment.start.properties.name,
   "weight": pathSegment.relationship.properties.Weight.low,
   "end": pathSegment.end.properties.name}); 
 })
```

Then I try:

```
 console.log(individual_path);
```

I am getting the following response (as one of the records has null value in the DB):

```
[ { start: 'A', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'P2' } ]
[]
[ { start: 'P1', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'A' },
  { start: 'A', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'P2' } ]
[ { start: 'P1', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'A' } ]
```

My question, how can I replace an empty array (while looping over the set of records) with non-empty, like this:

```
[ { start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' } ]
```

to have at the end something like:

```
[ { start: 'A', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'P2' } ]
 *[ { start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' } ]*
[ { start: 'P1', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'A' },
  { start: 'A', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'P2' } ]
[ { start: 'P1', weight: 0.6180339887498948, end: 'A' } ]
```

I was not quite clear, I will add the console.log(px); output:

```
Path {
  start:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'A', type: 'string' } },
  end:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 2, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'P2', type: 'string' } },
  segments:
   [ PathSegment { start: [Object], relationship: [Object], end: [Object] } ],
  length: 1 }
Path {
  start:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'A', type: 'string' } },
  end:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'A', type: 'string' } },
  segments: [],
  length: 0 }
Path {
  start:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'P1', type: 'string' } },
  end:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 2, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'P2', type: 'string' } },
  segments:
   [ PathSegment { start: [Object], relationship: [Object], end: [Object] },
     PathSegment { start: [Object], relationship: [Object], end: [Object] } ],
  length: 2 }
Path {
  start:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'P1', type: 'string' } },
  end:
   Node {
     identity: Integer { low: 1, high: 0 },
     labels: [ 'concept' ],
     properties: { name: 'A', type: 'string' } },
  segments:
   [ PathSegment { start: [Object], relationship: [Object], end: [Object] } ],
  length: 1 }
```

As you can see one of the blocks has an empty element segment, namely the second path block. What I need is to be able to replace an empty element, with object of the type (start: '', weight: , end:'')

And here is the console.log(px.segments);:

```
[ PathSegment {
    start: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] },
    relationship:
     Relationship {
       identity: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       end: [Object],
       type: 'link',
       properties: [Object] },
    end: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] } } ]
[]
[ PathSegment {
    start: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] },
    relationship:
     Relationship {
       identity: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       end: [Object],
       type: 'link',
       properties: [Object] },
    end: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] } },
  PathSegment {
    start: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] },
    relationship:
     Relationship {
       identity: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       end: [Object],
       type: 'link',
       properties: [Object] },
    end: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] } } ]
[ PathSegment {
    start: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] },
    relationship:
     Relationship {
       identity: [Object],
       start: [Object],
       end: [Object],
       type: 'link',
       properties: [Object] },
    end: Node { identity: [Object], labels: [Array], properties: [Object] } } ]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: On which variable you are  doing console.log on? Please mention that

Comment: sorry, my mistake, already done, I thought it was clear

Comment: Note that `map()` already builds a new array. By building `individual_path` yourself and calling `.push()` you are using much more memory than necessary.

Comment: thanks for input, but I am trying to parse the response and then combine different things in a joint output according to a template, I mentioned, that I have a nested object

Comment: @ArtemNazarenko Check my answer below for one solution. Also Asaf Aviv's answer will work if you are building up a 2D array.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How can you the return the expected output not in a 2D array ?

Comment: @AsafAviv The code given by the OP only shows building an array of objects called `individual_path`. It does **not** show how this array is used. I think the assumption we both make that it is added to another array to build a 2D array is reasonable, but this is still just an assumption. Note that the output is from logging each of these arrays as they are build, not from logging a 2D array. There are no commas after each array in the output.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I agree. we cant see how `pathSegmet` looks like in the `map` function too, he says it can be an empty array but try to push an `object` to `individual_path`

Comment: @ArtemNazarenko do `console.log(px.segments)` put the things here. Make it easier for everyone to solve your problem by including all of the possible information that can be a function of your outcome see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code where you are doing `console.log()`.

```
if (!individual_path.length){ 
   individual_path.push({ start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' });
}
```

If by doing `console.log()` gives an empty array `[]` then it's `length == 0` and we know `0 == false` all of this is true.

Also, use `.map` when you are returning an array. For now, `forEach` seems to do the job.

```
px.segments.forEach((pathSegment) => {                                                                                          
  individual_path.push({                          
   "start": pathSegment.start.properties.name,
   "weight": pathSegment.relationship.properties.Weight.low,
   "end": pathSegment.end.properties.name
   }); 
});
```

Live example of what I meant

```js
let individual_path = [];
if (!individual_path.length) {
   individual_path.push({ start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' });
}
console.log(individual_path) // should give that object
```

So your code becomes

```
if (!individual_path.length){ 
   individual_path.push({ start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' });
}
console.log(individual_path);
```

Comment: It just returns this object { start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' } and I need to incorporate it inside. I also added some additional info to my post.

Comment: Try to put the code at the top where you put `console.log()` @ArtemNazarenko

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working, thank you again!

Comment: Note that `forEach()` that calls `push()` can be replaced by `map()` with `return`

Answer (score -1):

First, I suggest taking advantage of the new array `map()` already builds:

```
var individual_path = px.segments.map(function(pathSegment){                                                                                          
  return {                          
   "start": pathSegment.start.properties.name,
   "weight": pathSegment.relationship.properties.Weight.low,
   "end": pathSegment.end.properties.name};
 };
```

Now if this is empty, just replace it with the desired array:

```
if (individual_path.length === 0) {
    individual_path = [ { start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' } ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and valuable advice!

Comment: Your individual_path is an array so doing `!` on an empty array will not give result as what you want. The second line just overwrites the whole array. Do check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-an-array-is-empty-or-exists

Comment: weegee is right, but anyway thank you for your efforts

Comment: @weegee Here I am intentionally overwriting the array inside the `if`. However, it appears that `!individual_path` always evaluates to `false`. I think an explicit comparison will be more correct.

Comment: @ArtemNazarenko I fixed the problems in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you, I already marked your answer as useful and thank you for giving an advice on proper use of map.

Answer (score -1):

```
const individual_path = px.segments.length
  ? segments.map(pathSegment => ({
      start: pathSegment.start.properties.name,
      weight: pathSegment.relationship.properties.Weight.low,
      end: pathSegment.end.properties.name,
    }))
  : [{ start: 'A', weight: 0.0, end: 'A' }];
```

Comment: @weegee That comment doesn't negate this answer which directly addresses the quesiton.

Comment: Yes @Code-Apprentice but map returns an array and he is using it in place of forEach. This is why the downvote. Else it directly addresses the question. I didn't close it as Not an answer

Comment: @weegee The OP is using map, That's why i also used map. he doesn't state anywhere that he doesn't want to mutate the array and we clearly can't see how the entire object looks like.