# How to check if a nested array is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I check whether a nested array is empty or not? The array looks like this when there is no data:

```
const data = [ [  ] ]
```

And if it has data it looks like this:

```
const data = [
  [{"Product": 7  }]
]
```

To check if it is empty I am doing the following which does not work:

```
if (!Array.isArray(data[0][0]) || data[0][0].length === 0) {
  return "Data is empty"
}
```

1. What I don't understand is why `!Array.isArray(data[0][0])` returns true, which means the nested array is not an array (which is strange because it *is* an array, just empty). According to the docs, `Array.isArray([])` returns true so how can `!Array.isArray(data[0][0]` return true?
2. The `data[0][0].length` part throws an error saying `"TypeError: "data[0][0] is undefined""`. Why would that be the case?
3. That leads to the question of how to check if a nested array is empty or not?

Comment: it should be `data[0].length`

Comment: You only have one level of nesting but you're trying to do two. Just change it to `data[0]` instead.

Comment: so yeah just remove the extra [0]

Comment: `data[0][0]` is `undefined` (`data[0]` is an empty array), which indeed isn't an array

Comment: Looks like a simple oversight. `data` is the parent array. It has one item in it which is the child array. So to access the first item of `data` (the child array) you have to do `data[0]`. I went one level too deep!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data[0][0]` is the first element of nested array: for first example it is `undefined`, for second object `{"Product": 7  }`. You need to check `data[0]` - it is first nested array, so you need the following:

```
if (!Array.isArray(data[0]) || data[0].length === 0) {
    return "Data is empty"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do `something` like this:

```
function checkIfEmpty(array) {
  return Array.isArray(array) && (array.length == 0 || array.every(checkIfEmpty));
}


console.log(checkIfEmpty([[{"name":"something"}]])); // false
console.log(checkIfEmpty([[]])); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether an array is empty like this:

```
if (Array.isArray(a) && a.length) {
     // whatever you would like to do
}
```

A very comprehensive explanation you can find in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743392/503413). So, looking at your concrete question that would mean the following:

```js
const data = [[]]

if (Array.isArray(data[0]) && data[0].length === 0) {
     // whatever you would like to do
     console.log("empty array")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
yourNestedArray.flat().length > 0 ? 'some content' : 'im empty';
```

Flat a builtin function of the javascript Array class that flattens a multidimensional array by iterating through all nested items and concats them to a 1d array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Bot i have edit the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Use should first apply Array.prototype.flat() an then check the length of a resulting array.