# How to check in javascript if a list contains any element?

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

How to check if a list is not empty?

```
if (serialNumbersList.Any())     //c# expression equivalent
{
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: (sorry, but - have you heard of _search engines_?) Does this answer your question? [Check if an array is empty or exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-an-array-is-empty-or-exists)

Comment: afaik, javascript does not have lists, but arrays. But .net and c# do have both arrays and lists. @FranzGleichmann Likely OP didnt know enough javascript to link their question to arrays.

Comment: @Cleptus that is true, but since javascript is, well... javascript, the distinction is practically without meaning.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I was commenting the posibility that OP could have done some searching but failed because of not searching using the correct terms. The "_have you heard of search engines_" is a bit rude imho.

Comment: I am writing code in mvc razorpages. I can use c# and JS there but sometimes i cannot connect those two langs. I didnt know JS doesnt have Lists :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript there are no lists but arrays, and you can check their `length` property

```js
if(serialNumberList.length > 0) { 
    // Do your stuff
}
```