# How can I check the condition to show the text from makeText

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I want to show "Favorite is empty" when there is no data to retrieve. However, it only work for else statement and it doesn't work in if statement . How can I check it is empty or not. I want to do like this the program will work as I coded when user click the button. But if there is not data to work when user click the button, program should show text from if statement

Here is my code

```
if(wishlist_item.size()>=1){
                    L1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if(a.isEmpty()){
                                Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this,web_view2.class);
                                launchWish.putExtra("k",a);
                                startActivity(launchWish);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: "it only work for else statement" what do you mean by that? that it always go straight to else? have you debugged your code? have you add some basic prints/loggings just to check the values of the variables you are comparing?

Comment: else statement work if there is data to show in database. But if statement doesn't work if there is not data to show in database. I want to show the text message like "no book" if user click the button and no data @Stultuske

Comment: ok, so what is your point? the comparison works perfect, your Toast.makeText call just doesn't do what you think it should do?

Comment: I think if (a.isEmpty) it should work or is there anything that I need to add more in if (a.isEmpty) this code? @Stultuske

Comment: we don't even know what your code should do. We also don't know what value a has at that point. You are very unclear in what is actually going wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show makeText text if variable is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006511/how-can-i-show-maketext-text-if-variable-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
L1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(wishlist_item.size() > 0) {
            Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this,web_view2.class);
            String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
            launchWish.putExtra("k",a);
            startActivity(launchWish);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro @Darkman I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a.isEmpty()){
```

most likely a.isEmpty is not working
you've got to find another method to ascertain if a is empty or not

HTH
traja47

Comment: can you tell me the similar work way or other way to show @Trajano Roberto

Comment: how can check if a is empty or not @Trajano Roberto

Comment: you've got to search on google the technology you are using; example in JavaScript = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-an-array-is-empty-or-exists