# How can I show makeText text if variable is empty

Tags: java, android, database

When I check this "a" variable is empty or not I got an error message `"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()'"`

"a" has this data ""http://www.librarything.com/isbn/9780071792745" which is from firebase database.

Here is my code

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                List<String> wishlist_item = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    wishlist_item.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }

                //list 1
                if(wishlist_item.size()>=1){
                    L1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if(a.contains(null)){
                                Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this,web_view2.class);
                                launchWish.putExtra("k",a);
                                startActivity(launchWish);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

I want the program to show "Favourite is empty" when there is no data in "a"
how can I check if a is empty or not?

Comment: If a is of String type, why not just check a == null? Or a.length() == 0?

Comment: I tried both of them but if "a" has no data in database, app doesn't show makeText message "Favorite is empty" @tomerpacific. How can I show this  message if a is empty?

Comment: Your current condition is if a contains null and not if a is null. There is a difference between the two. Also, your outer if guard checks if the Wishlist_item size is equal or greater than 1. If it is empty, you can present your message in the else part.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to verify that the variable "a" is null, and second, if not,
check that it has empty value, so the code will look something like this :

```
if( (a==null) || (a!=null & a.isEmpty())){
                            Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this,web_view2.class);
                            launchWish.putExtra("k",a);
                            startActivity(launchWish);
                        }
```

isEmpty() is in java 6 and above, if java 5 or less, replace with a.length()==0.

Comment: Sir it doesn't work still no makeText "Favourite is empty" @Hicham

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check if DataSnapshot is exist or not. If it's exist add your items to your list. If list is empty show your Toast message.

```
 myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot){
            List<String> wishlist_item = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (postSnapshot.exists()) {
                    wishlist_item.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            if (wishlist_item.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(wish_list.this, "Favourite is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                L1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    String a = wishlist_item.get(0);
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent launchWish = new Intent(wish_list.this, web_view2.class);
                        launchWish.putExtra("k", a);
                        startActivity(launchWish);
                    }
                });
            }
```